# Tracking Highest Occupied Index of Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array into which I am frequently (and effectively randomly) adding and removing elements. Is there an algorithm for keeping track of the highest occupied index of the array?

Right now the best that I can think of is the following:

1. Keep track of the highest occupied index in a variable (ie. HOI).
2. When getting the next free index in the array check if it is higher than HOI, if it is assign that index to HOI
3. When removing an item if that item is at the HOI index then scan backwards from HOI until an occupied index is found and assign that to HOI

This should work but it's not particularly elegant so I was wondering if anyone knows of a cleaner solution

Comment: How big can the array be?

Comment: Why is this bad? That seems like a fine solution (without stating your specific language). Although you probably can use library data structures in most languages.

Comment: @dtech: It's not terrible it just seems like the kind of thing someone much smarter than me has figured out how to do in constant time ;) Oh and right now I'm writing in C++

Comment: @nhahtdh: Realistically it will be ~1000 elements and worse case it could be as large as 2^16

Comment: @Huhwha: I think the solution is fine, as long as there are a reasonable number of entries in the array when you remove (more entries means that there is a higher chance that you don't have to go through too many entries to find the highest index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It greatly depends on the density of the array.

For an array that's at least moderately dense, your solution is fine, since the next item won't be too far.

For a very sparse array, a secondary data structure of indices may be a good idea (e.g. a [max heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)).

Are you stuck with an array? You should always consider reviewing your choice of data structure. From here, it's difficult to tell what would be best because I don't know enough about the problem you're trying to solve.

Or you can consider **a slightly more complex version of your solution:**

- Have an set (sorted array is fine if small) of max 5 (or so) of the highest indices.
- On insert, add into this set only if it's bigger than the smallest element (remove the smallest element if it would have more than 5 elements).
- On remove, remove from the set if it exists. If the set is empty, store the removed index.
- On get highest, simply return the max in the set. If the set is empty, go backwards from the stored index to find the max (and add it to the set).

Comment: Note that the number of items in the set (5 here) should be based on the maximum number of subsequent removals you do. If you alternate removal/addition, 2 are fine. If you can remove 50% of the items before adding another one this might not be a good solution.